# Determining if a symmetric matrix is positive definite

Tags: matrices, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite

I have a symmetric matrix where all non-diagonal elements are positive and identical, and all diagonal elements are identical as well. For example, the $3 \times 3$ version of this matrix has the following form: 
$$  \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
2a+b & a & a \\
a & 2a+b & a \\
a & a & 2a+b \end{array} \right)  $$

Note that $a>0\ , b>0$. For such a simple form, is there an easy way of determining that the above matrix is positive definite in the general $n \times n$ 
 case? I'd like to show that the matrix is still positive definite when the dimension is higher. Thank you.

Comment: The [criterion of Sylvester](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester's_criterion) is well-adapted to your case.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Beat me to it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes. Your matrix can be written as
$$(a+b)I + a ee^T$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix and $e$ is the vector of ones. This is a sum of a symmetric positive definite (SPD) matrix and a symmetric positive semidefinite matrix. Hence it is SPD.

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful

Comment: It would be cool to actually show that $ee^T$ is positive semidefinite:  $x^T e e^T x = (e^Tx)^T(e^Tx)$; since $e^Tx$ is a scalar $(e^T x)^T = e^T x$ whence $x^T e e^T x = (e^T x)^2 \ge 0$.  ***Endorsed!***  Cheers!

Comment: @SelinH You are very welcome.

Comment: @RobertLewis Thank your for your kind words. I often find it difficult to select the right level of detail.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Carl's answer (+1) you can use the [Gershgorin circle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem) which is one I'll often try when I see diagonally dominant matrices like this one.

For each row, the sum of the absolute values of the off-diagonal entries is $2a$. The theorem then says that every eigenvalue is in a closed disc of radius $2a$ centered at the diagonal elements $2a + b$, so for any eigenvalue $\lambda$ we have $\lambda \geq b > 0$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{bmatrix} 
2a+b &    a &    a\\   
   a & 2a+b &    a\\
   a &    a & 2a+b\end{bmatrix} = (a+b) \, \mathrm I_3 + a \, 1_3 1_3^\top = (a+b) \, \mathrm I_3 + 3a \left(\frac{\, 1_3}{\sqrt{3}}\right) \left(\frac{\, 1_3}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^\top$$

Hence, the **eigenvalues** are $4a + b$ and $a+b$, with multiplicities $1$ and $2$, respectively. Since $a, b > 0$, both eigenvalues are positive, i.e., the given symmetric matrix is positive definite.